# Link resized images to their full-size version

Tags: discussion, feature-request

#### The Facts

1. Images inside questions/answers are resized to fit within the container width.
2. Yet they are stored *as is*, meaning with their original resolution, for instance.

---

#### The Question

Why not provide some (easy-to-use) means to display images at their respective full-size?

---

#### An Example

Here is an image taken from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95981/generate-advanced-custom-fields-box-in-custom-admin-menu-page):

[image: An Example]

---

#### The Current Way of Displaying an Image at Full-Size

*Operations*:

- right-click image;
- select browser-specific context menu entry;
- see image at full-size;
- close tab/window (if opened in new tab/window) or *go back* to previous page (meaning the question).

---

#### A *Slightly* Better Way

Link image to its full-size version.
Thus, one only has to click once, then hit <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> (to go back).

---

#### A *Better* Way

Use some modal overlay to display the full size-image.
One click to display, click again (on image or somewhere else) to close.

---

#### The Discussion

What do you think? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the link manually already:

[image]

Code:

```
[![image][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQwr9.png
```

Overlays are sometimes hard to use, especially on smaller screens.

Comment: Yes, I know, and this is also easy (as I stated I'd like to have an _easy-to-use_ means), however, this is not what I'd call _comfortable_. A comfortable way would be to provide the user a checkbox (or a two-radio-button group) to just include the image or wrap it with a full-size link. Of course, you're right that overlays (especially when dealing with full-screen resolution images) are not that good when your resolution is smaller than the one the image was taken on.

Comment: Addition: I'm not (only) talking about making it easier for the one adding the image to the post, but also (or even _rather_) about making it easier for the ones reading the question with the resized image only. It's more the built-in automatism that I'd like to have (maning, the option would be set to include the link for the image by default).

Answer (score 1):

Side note regarding embedded images: we can display thumbnail versions of an image, appending `s` and `m` to its name.

**Small linked to full**:

```
[![image][1]][2]
<sup>*click to enlarge* ⤴</sup>

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQwr9s.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQwr9.png
```

> [image]
>   <sup>*click to enlarge* ⤴</sup>

**Medium linked to full**:

```
[![image][3]][4]
<sup>*click to enlarge* ⤴</sup>

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQwr9m.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQwr9.png
```

> [image]
>   <sup>*click to enlarge* ⤴</sup>